# Avoid showing the same phrase in the loops

Tags: customization, loop

I use this multiple loops to show the sold of some wears, so if there are the sold (meta_value=yes) the txt or presentation must be showing one time in top, and others products in bottom, and if the (meta_value=non) the users see a msg like : No sold available.

in this loop the only problem is the presentation, it showing many time in the top, so pls how can i let it to be showing one time?

Thanks

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=wear&meta_key=sold&meta_value=yes'); ?>    
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <p>I'd like this presentation to be showing one time if there is the sold</p>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php rewind_posts(); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1>Yes, there is some sold</h1>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <h1>No sold available</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hello! I'm not sure what you mean by "the sold" can you rephrase that or explain what you mean? Also I notice you used the `query_posts` function, this should be avoided, never use `query_posts`. If you want to modify what gets shown on a page, use the `pre_get_posts` filter to change what WordPress fetches from the database. Don't create a second new query and discard the first. If you need to create a secondary post loop, use `WP_Query`

Comment: Hello,
 **The Sold** is the **promotion of the price** of certain clothes.
My goal is to have a loop who will search in the clothes store (`post_type=wear`), if there are a promotion (`meta_key=sold`), if yes (`meta_value=yes`) the loop will first show a **presentation** just one time, and then to post all the **articles of Promotion/Sold clothes**.
else if there is no Sold (`meta_value=no`), the phrase will be **No sold available**
This is what i wanna do with that Loop.
Thanks

Comment: If that's the case why have. post loop at all? Why not just check `have_posts`? The solution to your problem isn't WP specific, it's fundamental PHP/programming knowledge of how if/while/for loops work

Comment: I'm not really expert in the WP coding also in PHP, can you please recreate that code with the best practice of coding?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, And thanks goes to [@lai32290](https://wordpress.org/support/users/lai32290/)

My goal is to have a loop who will search in the ***clothes store*** (`post_type=wear`), if there are a promotion (`meta_key=sold`), if yes (`meta_value=yes`) the loop will first show a presentation just one time, and then to post ***all the articles*** of Promotion/Sold clothes.
else, if there is no Sold (`meta_value=no`), the phrase will be : No sold available

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=wear&meta_key=sold&meta_value=yes'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
    <p>I'd like this presentation to be showing one time if there is the sold</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1>Yes, there is some sold</h1>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <h1>No sold available</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```